# For what $\lambda$ do non-negative solution to $(A-\lambda I)x = b$ exist?

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, generalized-eigenvector

I am interested in understanding for what values of $\lambda$ is $(A - \lambda I)^{-1} b$ component-wise non-negative. Here $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a $n\times 1$ vector.

I know there is work related to this problem when $A$ and $b$ are non-negative as well as well as when $A$ is underdetermined. However, I am interested in a more general case where $A$ is an arbitrary square matrix.

I also know this is related to convex optimization and finding feasible points. However, I am not just interested in finding such a point, but characterizing all such points.

Comment: Forms like the above occur naturally in trust region methods, but not with the non negativity constraint.

Comment: Can you provide any references on this problem when $A$ is nonnegative? I think I have a full solution in that case, more or less. So I'd like to see what is already known.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember why I was interested in this question

Comment: I just found a paper: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0606042 that solves this problem for nonnegative matrices. This paper shows exactly what I discovered on my own... arg!---the story of life as a mathematician, always discovering what is already known! I still haven't seen anything for general matrices though.